# In-memory GPG signing (or possibly using a temporary keyring)

Tags: python, gnupg, in-memory

I'm working on a web app that needs to create GPG signatures for files as they're uploaded by someone on staff. However, for security, I don't want to keep the signing key on the webserver, even though it's protected by a passphrase.

One solution I was looking into was to prompt for the private key on startup of the webapp, and store it in memory. Then, pass in the text of the key when signing, instead of using a key from the keyring.

However, I've done a lot of looking around and can't find any way to do this. GPG expects the key to be in the keyring. Any suggestions, or better ideas? I'm using Python, but any command-line tools/scripts would work great as well.

(I realize I can always just generate signatures manually, on a non-public-facing machine...but I wanted to investigate this first, because if it's possible it would be much more convenient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/450760) on superuser might give you some ideas. It's written for encrypting with a public key, but it would be easy to adapt. The long and short: you could use `gpg --homedir SOMEDIR`, where SOMEDIR was a directory on a tmpfs filesystem like the traditional /dev/shm.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, that could work...theoretically an intruder could still snag the key in the brief window where it was saved there, if they'd gotten in and were looking for it, but that seems unlikely. I'll do a little more looking.

Comment: @peppergrower: I'm not sure I understand what theory you're talking about. ... What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Assuming the key was held in memory most of the time, I'd still need to briefly write it to the filesystem for long enough to do the signing, and then remove the key from the filesystem. While the key was on the filesystem, theoretically someone with access could read it. Granted, that's unlikely, given a < 1s window.

Comment: @peppergrower: Indeed, lots of things are possible. I can't imagine being willing to upload a private key to a webserver, but anwhooo ... It seems some custom python funness might be ideal for highest security here, but in case you weren't aware, [tmpfs filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) are in-ram. This doesn't prevent other users from accessing files on such filesystems (like `/dev/shm/`) if the permissions are open, but still. ...

Comment: Yeah, I don't like it either, and I'll recommend against doing anything like this, despite the convenience (and suggest signing on a separate machine instead). Hopefully the client understands the need for security. But if we did have to do it, I think your answer would be the best way available.