# GPG: signing and encrypting with keys not in keyring

Tags: gnupg

I have interest in using GPG to sign and encrypt messages, but the GPG keys are not in my private or public keyrings, they are in separate files. Is there any way to sign and encrypt messages with keys in files, rather than using keys in my keyring?

I've looked at https://superuser.com/questions/450759/simple-pgp-encryption-in-one-step/450760#450760, but it involves creating a temporary keyring in a temporary directory, and that's not quite what I want to do.

I've also looked at [In-memory GPG signing (or possibly using a temporary keyring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984992/in-memory-gpg-signing-or-possibly-using-a-temporary-keyring), but wants an in-memory key...

Comment: GnuPG is not able to use keys not imported to the keyring. You can use key files as public keyring, but that does not work out with private keys, also not with GnuPG 2.1 which merged the keys (I just had a try). Anyway: This question is a bad fit for Stack Overflow, as it is about tool usage and not about software development at all. Better ask such questions at Super User.

Comment: I'm writing software that is driving gpg from Python. Right now I'm throwing things into a temporary directory and building keyrings, then throwing them away...